# how to properly handle POST in a custom Spring Data Rest controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

in my Spring Data Rest application I have a standard repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

        List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

I also have a custom controller, which will implement some additional logic upon HTTP POST:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PersonController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> savePerson(@RequestBody Person person, UriComponentsBuilder b, @RequestParam Map<String, ?> id) {


        UriComponents uriComponents = 
                b.path("/people/").buildAndExpand();
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
           responseHeaders.setLocation(uriComponents.toUri());
           responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World\n\n", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to save my "Person" entity within this controller, since I'm not using Hibernate Entity Manager explicitly?
The "person" parameter is just a POJO, so it does not have any persistance CRUD methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Person class used in the PersonRepository is same as whatever you are using in the controller to map RequestBody to, then in the controller method you can just do personRepository.save(person) -- Assuming personRepository is an Autowired instance of PersonRepository class.

I am guessing that, you are experimenting with spring data rest https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/ . If that's the case, you might have in-memory database com.h2database:h2 in your class path. Thats why, in the given example, everything is just working without you even configuring the database or adding any JPA annotations to your person class. So, you can still do personRepository.save(person) from your custom controller without having any of the JPA annotations in your Person class.